# External from to DataExtension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, leads, form

Here's the main idea:
There's a custom form on my website and I want visitors to sign up through it. Their data must be posted to a DataExtension.
So far, I've found the CloudPages form, but it's way limited when talking about customization and does not fulfill my needs.

How could I send data from my website to a DataExtension? Is there any kind of documentation on it that I haven't found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Web Collect](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/) - this allows you to add/update to a DE in marketing cloud. Keep scrolling to see how to set up with DEs and for sample code.